# Number of column values greater than 0 for given row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
col1  col2  col3
0     0     .4
.3    1     0
0     0     .8
```

I'd like to create a new column which counts the number of column values greater than 0 in the other three rows:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     .4    1
.3    1     0     2
0     0     .8    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `apply` function:

```
## Example Data
dd = data.frame(col1 = c(0, .3, 0), col2=c(0, 1, 0),
                        col3=c(0.4, 0, 0.8))
apply(dd, 1, function(i) sum(i > 0))
```

So to add this too your existing data frame:

```
dd$col4 =  apply(dd, 1, function(i) sum(i > 0))
```

---

Alternatively, we could convert the data frame to logical values then use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(dd > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `Reduce` with `+` after looping over the columns to create a `list` of logical `vector`s

```
dd$col4 <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(dd, `>`, 0))
dd
#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1  0.0    0  0.4    1
#2  0.3    1  0.0    2
#3  0.0    0  0.8    1
```